# Convert Gif image to Base64 while retaining loop count

Tags: html, base64, gif

I have a gif image modified to play only once using https://ezgif.com/loop-count

If I put the `src` of the `img` tag to the URL of the gif everything works fine, the gif plays only once in the browser.

But if I convert the gif to Base64 URL and assign it as the `src` the gif loops infinitely in the browser, I want the gif to play only once when it's converted to Base64 URL, using jQuery if needed.

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,...>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to make a gif loop 1 time converting with this website https://www.base64-image.de/

Since the base64 string is greater then the SO limit I created a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/59ox80ws/

```
body {
  background: url('data:image/gif;base64, ... ');
}
```